# "hasClass" synonym in rails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

In my app I need to check if certain `span` with `id="transaction_sign"` has a class `negative` and if it is - add "minus" to number, which user has entered in a field and save it in negative form to database.

In fact, if using jQuery and Rails together I need to do this:

```
def add_sign_to_transaction
    if $('#transaction_sign').hasClass('negative') {
        @transaction.amount *= -1 
    };
end
```

But, of course I can't do in in my `transaction_controller.rb` file, where I need to put this `def` with `before_filter`.

Is there any way to check css on a page in rails? Or maybe I need some certain gems for it?

Comment: Why should your controller know anything about your view's CSS classes?

Comment: I've found solution, which is more appropriate to my app. I've added the second column with negative numbers and change fields (positive - negative) by jQuery `click` event. So, changing sign is not necessary now. But I still don't understand how to tell controller to change the sign from view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your form should send either:

1. Transformed data in the first place, or
2. Enough additional data to do any transformations on the server side.

View-layer representations are brittle substitutes for appropriate models.

The *technical* answer to your question is no, unless the view layer is altered only by server-side code and not JS. If the client alters the style(s) then you should either send the right data or a flag. The flag could, of course, be a hidden field set to the style of the form element, or a boolean triggered by the presence of a given style. IMO that's the wrong approach: send a negative number.

Answer (score 0):

You should really be doing this in your JS file. Find the span, then add to your counter, and submit an ajax call to save the negative number to your database.